# xlsx file do not open in microsoft office and work fine in open office

Tags: php, file, excel-2007, xlsx, openoffice-calc

I am working with file-handling in php and generate a report file after certain things is over and type of files are .csv and .xlsx. Now problem is that csv file work properly and open currectly in oppen office and ms office 2007 both, while excel file doesn't open in ms-office 2007 which is work fine in oppen office. here something i want to add my file version was not old.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So how are you generating the xlsx file? PHP doesn't have any built in options to do this, so you must be using a 3rd party library - which library, how are you calling it, etc? Show code

Comment: Could you please add the code you're using, and eventually post the xlsx and csv file ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply.. let me explain.

Comment: actually i have developed one module in moodle using code of core php and there is no issue right! module's work is that it's generate csv and xlsx file contains name and all details of student who has attempt a quiz.and it works file. now when i download file from selecting option of csv from dropdown then it shows correct information in open office as well as ms office in excel..but not happen this same thing in case of excel i.e xlsx it work fine in open office but not in ms-office 2007, it shows wrong format or invalid file.

Comment: Over different versions, moodle has used different libraries for generating Excel files; so your answer doesn't really help us identify what could be going wrong; but I'm guessing that it's invalid headers for the filetype

Comment: Thanks Mark for replay, but as i told report is being generate properly, only issue with it's extension like .xlsx will not work in ms-office 2007 and it nicely work or opened in open office. if i am renaming it csv instead of xlsx after download then it shows right record as i wish but not with xlsx. here i am adding some code may it'll help you to guide me!!

Comment: $fp = fopen('report/upload/file.xlsx', 'w+');                 fputcsv($fp, array($quiz_user,$quiz_name,$q_result['name'],$option,$given_answer_result['answer'],number_format($q_result['fraction'],0) ==1 ? $q_result['answer']: ""));

Comment: and here is a code from where i download the file of generated report.

Comment: else
{                                                                   
 $filepath = "http://localhost/mod/quiz/report/upload/";                                                                                                                                               
 $filename = "file.xlsx";
 header("Content-Type: application/excel");
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 flush();
 readfile($filepath . rawurlencode($filename));

}
?>

Comment: <?php if($_REQUEST['name']=='CSV') { $filepath = "localhost/mod/quiz/report/upload/";; $filename = "file.csv"; header("Content-Type: application/csv"); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'); header("Pragma: no-cache"); flush(); readfile($filepath . rawurlencode($filename)); }